# Are The Mechanic's tools and gadgets real?

Tags: realism, mechanic-resurrection

Are the tools/gadgets/chemicals used by Arthur Bishop (Jason Statham) in *Mechanic: Resurrection* real? I mean, do they work and exist in real life?

Things like the gum that he used for explosives and the chemical used to break the glass. And btw, what is the cream used for?

Comment: This is a great question! However, might I suggest you make your question about the cream a different question/post entirely? It seems like, while tangentially related, it's different enough that it requires a separate answer. But all in all, thanks for a great question, and I hope we can help you find the answer!

Comment: Pretty sure he drills a hole in the glass.

Comment: @Yorik but the glass dont breaks because of that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The gum that is used as explosives was not gum. If you pay attention in a previous scene you can watch Arthur roll out plastic explosive and cut it into gum size strips, then repacking them. The gum is essentially some plastic explosive disguised as gum.

The cream was just a shark deterrent.

Regarding the glass, most see through pools are made using some polycarbonate glass, which is also used in armored vehicles. I'm not sure wat exactly he used, but I'm sure there's some chemical that could be used in that way. After all, there is a huge amount of pressure on the bottom plates, and weakening the integrity does the job.